# Yes or No program for asking permission to rate an app

Tags: c++, char, cin

I am preety new in coding (like 2 weeks in) and I have been trying to make programs out of my mind to practice, so don't be so rough on me :D. What I tried today is to make a program that requires to insert a letter, because i have been playing with int function, so i wanted to change it a bit.
So I've been trying to make this work and although it executes the program, when you type a letter it just shuts the program down. Appreciate any help, and if you could explain the mistakes I did. Thank you all in advance!! :D

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    
    char Answer;
    char responsetype;

    std::cout<<"Please rate this app\n";
    std::cin>> Answer;
while (responsetype=false)
        if (Answer=='Y')
        {
            responsetype=true;
            std::cout<< "Thanks for rating :D\n";
            }
            else if (Answer/='Y')
            {
                if (Answer=='N')
                {
                    responsetype=true;
                    std::cout<< "awwww... Okay then.. :(\n";
                }
                    else(true);
                        responsetype=false;
                        std::cout<<"You need to answer Y or N :/\n";
            }
            
                
return 0;
```

Comment: What does while(responsetype=false) do?

Comment: I used it as, while this valuable (responsetype) is false, it should do a loop. so if you type something outside of 'Y' or 'N' it should do a loop.

Comment: `Answer /= 'Y'` is a division and most definitely not what you want. Inequality is done with `!=`

Comment: Did you mean to make responsetype a boolean and then check while(responsetype==false)? Or should it really be a char?

Comment: Well i tried with boolean but it would always type my first answer as a 'Y'.

Comment: `else(true);` is also weird to say the least, here you have an else clause with a single statement after that namely `(true);` that does nothing and the following 2 statements are executed regardless of the previous if's evaluation.

Comment: There are a couple of problems in this code, but first of all I would fix the indentation to more clearly see what the program does, and enable compiler warnings, those can be pretty helpful.

Comment: Ah okay so i used a wrong character? thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things I've changed:

1. Changing responsetype from char to boolean
2. Changed the overall structures to a switch case instead of if-statement
3. Added getchar() on the end so the program doesn't automatically shut down at the end

   ```
   #include <iostream>

   int main() {

   char Answer;
   bool responsetype = false;

   std::cout<<"Please rate this app\n";
   std::cin>> Answer;

   while (!responsetype){
      switch(Answer)
      {
        case 'Y':
          responsetype=true;
          std::cout<< "Thanks for rating :D\n";
          break;
        case 'N':
          responsetype=true;
          std::cout<< "awwww... Okay then.. :(\n";
          break;
        default:
          responsetype=false;
          std::cout<<"You need to answer Y or N :/\n";
      }
   }

   getchar(); // Asks for another input before closing console          
   return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: Okay i don't know yet about switch, getchar and case, so I will google it! Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: No problem. If the code works it would be nice if you could set it as the answer.

Comment: will do :D Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your code so I'm going to try to list the ones I spotted.

1. **while(responsetype=false)**
   seems to be the cause of your problem, you are assigning false to response here and then checking for responsetype which will always be false.
2. You'll want `std::cin>>Answer;` inside of your for loop so the user can actually change their anser.
3. `if (Answer/='Y')` => `if (Answer!='Y')`
4. `else(true);`
   this does not do anything, you could delete it all together, but what you originally wanted was probably `else{...}`